# regular expression in javascript - get content of divs

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get content of all divs where the content does not contain any html tags except `<br>` tags.

`str.match(/<div>.*?<\/div>/g);` gives all div contents whereas `str.match(/<div>([^<>])*<\/div>/g,);` gives div contents without any html tags.

I managed to get a solution. I can covert all `<br>` tags to some other codes, then use `str.match(/<div>([^<>])*<\/div>/g,);` and finally revert the `<br>` tags. I do not know whether this is a good solution.

Is it possible using regular expression to get all div contents without any html tags except `<br>`? Or a better solution exists? (preferably by not using look ahead or look behind). Thanks.

EDIT:
input string: `abcd <div>div</div> abcd <div>div with <br></div> <div>abcd div with <p> abcd</div>`

In this, i like to match `<div>div</div>` and `<div>div with <br></div>`

```js
var str = 'abcd <div>div</div> abcd <div>div with <br></div> <div>abcd div with <p> abcd</div>';

var res = str.match(/<div>.*?<\/div>/g);
document.write('<textarea>'+res+'</textarea>');

var res = str.match(/<div>([^<>])*<\/div>/g);
document.write('<textarea>'+res+'</textarea>');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Please share your input and desired output.  Your question will be marked as unclear if you don't share that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to parse HTML using regex, you're better off using something like jQuery.

Here is an example:

```js
var str = "abcd <div>div</div> abcd <div>div with <br></div> <div>abcd div with <p> abcd</div>";
var $e = $("<div></div>");
$e.html(str);
var result = $e.find("div").map(function(){
    return $(this).html();
}).get().join(" ");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```